# All threads stuck at "select () from /lib64/libc.so.6" with high mem usage in my C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gcc, g++

`enter code here`I have a binary that I am migrating from 32 bit to 64 bit.

I ran it and this was the result when I did `top -H -p <name of binary>` :

[image]

Note that all the entries are the threads of the same process.

So I decided that I must check what is happening inside each thread. Thus, I started attaaching to each process.

This was the result:

```
gdb attach 28608
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000039a40ccfc2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002b40b4d20178 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()


gdb attach 28472
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000039a40ccfc2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002b40b4d20178 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000002d00000000 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000300000002e in ?? ()
#4  0x0000003200000000 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000142cf418 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000142cf3f8 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000003900000038 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000003e0000003b in ?? ()
#9  0x0000004000000000 in ?? ()
#10 0x00000000142cf278 in ?? ()
#11 0x00000000142cf2f8 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000004800000047 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fffe259cd00 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fffe259cd70 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

gdb attach 28475
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000039a40ccfc2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002b40b4ee8f3c in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000069f50 in ?? ()
#4  0x00002b40b542e160 in ?? ()
#5  0x00002b40b4ee9e91 in ?? ()
#6  0x00002b40b5505681 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000140fede0 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

gdb attach 28609
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000039a40ccfc2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002b40b4d20178 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I am not quite sure what this select() function is.

Can you tell me what might be wrong here ? Why are all the threads stuck like that ? 
have you ever encountered something like this before ?

Comment: Have you compiled your app with `-g` key? The backtrace looks weird. It can be the result of a corrupted stack on the other hand.

Comment: @PavelDavydov yes, I had compiled with the -g option. And no, I did not find any signs of a corrupt stack apart from the weird stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) is an api call that allows you to monitor file descriptors for activity, at which point you will be notified and can carry out the activity (eg read or write).

It looks like your program has 4 threads that are each waiting on `select` to return.

Comment: I did have some trouble with the logging mechanism which writes to files before. This is a very god hint. Thanks.

Comment: Look also for [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which gives you similar functionality to `select` but without limitation on the highest file descriptor number (the size of `fd_set` is generally a compile-time limit). Read also about the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)